# Expected Indented Block with DJANGO Rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have just started with django and I am getting the error on line 1 in models.py,  I have not created a virtual environment and I have created app called wallet.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Wallet(models.Model):
    raddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False) 
    //Expected Indented Block here Error
    balance = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    sent = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    received = models.TextField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        self.raddress
        self.balance
        self.sent
        self.received
```

Also when I put my app in name in the installed apps under settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
/// 'wallets', I am trying to put it here
]
```

It gives me an error saying

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_frameworkwallet'
```

It just concatinates the two?

Comment: Strange.  Are you testing it with backward slashes, " \ ", since that would mean a new line in your code, and would explain both of the errors.

Comment: Can you share your views.py or urls.py file in wallets app?

Comment: strange when I reopened the project after reopening my laptop my created app (wallet) is just gone??, it is just a default django project with a few files? Where is my created app?